# My htaccess isn't working for a redirect permanent

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to do a permanent redirect with `.htaccess`, but it isn't working and I have no idea why.

RedirectPermanent / http://www.flunchinvite.fr

I'm trying to do a redirection from :  http://www.flunchinvite.com to: http://www.flunchinvite.fr.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

**edit**

I've just did a test to do a redirect to google, and it doesn't work either, whereas when I try to do a redirect with the same code on http://flunchinvite.fr it works. Do you know where that can come from ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to

```
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^flunchinvite.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.flunchinvite.cfr/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: Hum, doesn't work neither. But I really don't understand why it's not working :s

Answer (score 0):

Use Rewrite if it is an option:

http://www.gnc-web-creations.com/301-redirect.htm

> Another method we can use is via mod_rewrite. This requires that the
>   mod_rewrite module is active on your webserver. It usually is and is
>   done by the system administrators when they installed the webserver.
>   mod_rewrite is a very powerful URL re-writing engine and we will only
>   by scratching a hair on its head here.
>
> Again, in your .htaccess file
>
> RewriteEngine ON RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mynewdomain.com/$1
>   [R=301,L]
>
> The above example will re-map your old domain to a new one and issue a
>   301 status code (permanent redirect). So a request for
>
> http://olddomain.com/foobar.html will go to
>
> http://mynewdomain.com/foobar.html
>
> If you simply want to redirect all requests regardless of the page
>   requested to the new domain you could use:
>
> RewriteRule /.* http://mynewdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
>
> In this case no matter what file or directory is requested they will
>   all go to
>
> http://mynewdomain.com/ i.e., http://myolddomain.com/foobar.html
>
> will go to http://mynewdomain.com/
>
> The [R=301,L] means redirect the client and send a 301 status code
>   (R=301) and make this the last rule (L).

Comment: Just tried it, and it doesn't seem to work. 
It looks like nothing I do to rewrite is working

Comment: if mod_rewrite is disabled on your web server then it won't work. Another alternative might be to add both domains to the same hosting account (with the secondary name as a parked domain) - should achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I did a php redirection, I don't know why it's not ok on the htaccess. I'll see that another time. I'm going to bed

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at lines 5 and 6:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /demo2
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mathpdq\.com
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mathpdq.com/demo2/$1 [R=permanent,L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I could not get 301 redirects to work so I went with this. basically if the user goes in with mathpdq.com/demo2 it forces a redirect to www.mathpdq.com/demo2.

The stuff below line 6 is just the normal mapping into the php functions.

http://pastie.org/5364605